# Django forms and django-guardian: showing filtered list of UserObjectPermissions

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-guardian

I want an administrator to be able to assign/remove django-guardian permissions to a person and how they relate to a Project object, based on what permissions available to said object.

The screen to look like this:

[image: User dropdown followed by checklist of permissions]

The project is provided in the URL, which the view can see. I've created a custom form which takes a project as an input, like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from guardian.shortcuts import get_perms_for_model

class ProjectAssignmentForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.p = kwargs.pop('project')
        self.perms = [(x, x) for x in get_perms_for_model(self.p)]
        super(ProjectAssignmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['permission'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()

    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())  
    permission = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.perms)
```

This currently gives me a NameError, I think because I'm using `self` outside of the `__init__` method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing. Here's the answer - I almost had it:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from guardian.shortcuts import get_perms_for_model

class ProjectAssignmentForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectAssignmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['permission'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        choices=[(x, x) for x in get_perms_for_model(kwargs.pop('project'))])

  user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())  
  permission = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
```